# Using tf,py_func with pickle files in Dataset API

Tags: tensorflow, pickle

I am trying to use the Dataset API with my dataset, which are pickle files. These files contains my data which is a vector of floats and the labels which is a one hot vector.

I have tried using the tf.py_func to load the features but I am unable to do it as I have missmatching shapes. As, I am these pickle files which includes the label as well, I can not give it directly to the tuple as the example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#applying_arbitrary_python_logic_with_tfpy_func). So I am a bit lost on how to continue.

This is my code so far

```py
path = "my_dir_to_pkl_files"

pkl_files = glob.glob((path+"*.pkl"))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((pkl_files))
dataset = dataset.map(
               lambda filename: tuple(tf.py_func(
               load_features, [filename], [tf.float32])))
```

And here is my python function to read the features.

```py
def load_features(name):
    decoded = name.decode("UTF-8")
    if os.path.exists(decoded):
        with open(decoded, 'rb') as f:
            file = pickle.load(f)
            return file['features']
            # I have commented the line below but this should return
            # the features and the label in a one hot vector
            # return file['features'], file['targets']
    else:
        print("Something went wrong!")
        exit(-1)
```

I would expect Dataset API to return a tuple with N features and 1 hot vector for each sample in my batch. Instead im getting

> InvalidArgumentError: pyfunc_0 returns 30 values, but expects to see 1
>   values.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

**Edit:**
I show how my pickle file is. The features vector has a shape of [30,100]. I  attach the same file as well [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fzbv7klnprnbt58/features-1.pkl?dl=0).

```
{'features': array([[0.64864044, 0.71419346, 0.35874235, ..., 0.66058507, 0.89013242,
        0.67564707],
       [0.15958826, 0.38115951, 0.46636267, ..., 0.49682084, 0.08863887,
        0.17142761],
       [0.26925915, 0.27901399, 0.91624607, ..., 0.30269212, 0.47494327,
        0.43265325],
       ...,
       [0.50405357, 0.7441127 , 0.04308265, ..., 0.06766902, 0.87449393,
        0.31018099],
       [0.44777562, 0.30836258, 0.48148097, ..., 0.74899213, 0.97264324,
        0.43391464],
       [0.50583501, 0.56803691, 0.61290449, ..., 0.8350931 , 0.52897295,
        0.23731264]]), 'targets': array([0, 0, 1, 0])}
```

The error I got is after I try to get an element for the dataset

```py
dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
print(sess.run(next_element))
```

Comment: You should give a minial pickle file so that we can help you.

Comment: @giser_yugang I edited the question. I uploaded a file and post aswell its contents.

Comment: It's strange that I didn't encounter your mistake on `tensorflow=1.12` and `python=3.6`. When I use code `dataset = dataset.map(lambda filename: tuple(tf.py_func(load_features, [filename], [tf.float64])))`, I can run it.

Comment: I get the error when I try to get an element from the dataset.
_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
print(sess.run(next_element))_
Could it be this?

Comment: The code you get an element from the dataset is working properly on my machine. I can print your file content.